# How see data on bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have created an an app on my android, it connect to my PC with bluetooth, this app send data via bluetooth.

How can I see this received data on my pc?

> I use dont use a plug module on my pc it's the incorporate bluetooth, so he dont have a serial port

I have try find on google but all speak of transfered file.

Comment: Please see the help center (especially the parts about how to ask a good question). This question is far too broad and unclear for SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to open up a terminal on the PC that has an open connection to the appropriate COMM port (physical or virtual). If you have this connection open you can then see any data that comes in and accordingly can send data back out.

Basically, on either end you have a bluetooth connection. That is a replacement for a cable in essence. Assuming you are using a serial port profile this will allow bytes of data to be sent back and forth over Bluetooth. I believe you are at that stage.

The port on your PC receives the data but has no means of displaying it. An application such as 'SERIAL' for Mac OS, HyperTerminal or similar for Windows will be what you need to see the data.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

(Another way would be to write an application that interfaces to the serial port on your PC but, I wouldn't think that would be worth your while... the terminal application is what you need) :)

This website has a list of useful applications that will help you.

http://www.usconverters.com/index.php?main_page=page&id=15&zenid=4835fe9edad4ba7966f4cf6533711315

Comment: Yes but the bluetooth on my pc is no a plug , so he dont have a serial port. How i can connect to him ?

Comment: An actual port is known as a PHYSICAL port because it's an actual, real physical thing. In your case, as the adapter is perhaps internal, it will have something called a VIRTUAL port which basically pretends to be a real serial port, even though the computer doesn't actually have an actual port. So, you'd need to go to device manager / settings etc... and look at ports. You should then find details of the virtual port for your internal bluetooth adapter. 

Download one of the apps in the link I shared and you can then set the comm port in the app to your virtual one.

Comment: i try with this **Port_#0007.Hub_#0001** but he dont work

Comment: Well, for a start does your bluetooth adapter support the serial port profile ? I would assume it does as that is the most basic profile. In either case, what I've detailed above is an answer to your question of what you need to do. In terms of how you find the virtual comm port for your particular O/S and BT adapter, that's a different Google search!